# Repeat plot command with minor changes in R

Tags: r, plot, gnuplot

I made a plot in R and I want to repeat all the commands (like `plot()`, `legend()` or `line()`) that were carried out for this plot, with some minor changes. For example I want to set the axes to logarithmic scale and change the title of the plot.

In gnuplot I would use the `replot` command.

```
plot ...
set title "The same plot with logarithmic axes"
set logscale
replot
```

Is something like this possible in R. The only thing that comes to my mind of doing this (besides changing the values manually and re-run the lines of codes) would be setting up a function, that asks for all parameters that might be changed by the user.

Thanks for your help,

Sven

Answer (score 12, accepted):

R uses a pen and paper graphics model - once the plot has been drawn on the device that is it. If you want to change some aspect of the plot, you need to replay the graphics function calls that produce the plot with the changes made to the code.

Depending on what you are really doing there are two options:

1. If this is just for you, write code in a text editor / IDE that knows R and can send chunks of code at a time to R. That way the code to produce the figure is recorded in a separate script which you can paste into/send to R making the changes you need each time to the script.
2. If you are going to be doing this often, then write yourself a wrapper plotting function that encapsulates the plot code you want but allows you to pass in arguments to alter the aspects you want.

Lattice and ggplot2 are a little different as they are based on grid graphics and create objects that *when printed* produce a plot on the device. One can manipulate that object to alter what is drawn, and with grid one can push and pop things on to / off a viewport.

Comment: Just to add to Gavin's suggestions.  There is an update method for lattice plots, so if you save the created object then you can update things like titles using the update function.  The ggplot2 objects can be updated using '+'.